# PHP tabs or Separate pages

Tags: php, performance, tabs

I have a doubt regarding the tabs I have in my project. Its a user view page with multiple tabs in it. Each tab is having details like user basic info, social profile info, skills etc. The current setup is PHP tabs with `$_GET['tab']` value. There are different `$_GET['tab']` for each tabs and the if condition checks the `$_GET['tab']` variable and loads the content of include file in that tab. There are about 10 tabs and 10 if conditions in this page.

The page itself is having other include files like header, footer, side menu etc.

Me and my friend had a discussion on this and he suggests to have separate page for each tabs and avoid if conditions in the page.

My questions are:

1. Does the number of if conditions really make changes to the performance of the page?
2. Should I switch to separate page and have visual tab look?

Comment: 1) If it's 10 `if` or `switch` performances are really not a problem. 2) Primarily opinion based / Too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way would be to have an index.php file, that has the `$_GET['tab']` check and that uses `require_once()` or `include()` to load the tabs.

Example of index.php structure:

```
<?php

//...

require_once('header.php');

//...

if ($_GET['tab'] == '1')
{
    require_once('first_tab.php');
}
else if ($_GET['tab'] == '2')
{
    require_once('second_tab.php');
}

//...

require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

There's no reason to worry about performance. Using this logic makes it easier for you to have cleaner code and avoid 1k lines files.

Comment: If you have 10 tabs, create 10 ```if```s is nonsense, just use a white list of possible values, and if the tab value is in the whitelist then you just need to ```include('tabs/' . $_GET['tab'] . '.php')```. You just make the tab filename the similar to the tab name code, then you can include it directly (you must check that your tab variable is valid, thus using a whitelist of options is a MUST to avoid security issues)

Comment: Thanks @mTorres and that's an interesting point. I must do it like this I think!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should code in such a way that the script completes processing in the lowest time on the server (using less resources) and the page output is returned to the user fastest on the browser. However, sometimes other things such as development and maintenance time come into the picture. ie, If you could save much time in development and maintenance, you can go with the option even if it could cause the script run time to be increased by a fraction of ms. So you should always find the best case scenario in any such situation.

In this case, you are going to have a page with multiple tabs. So just compare both methods:

**Single page with 10 tabs:**

**Pros:**
Needs only a single file. However, the development and maintenance time would be more or less equal here. Because although you don't have to create another page and include the template files, you will have to add the IF statements. And for maintenance, when a tab is removed, you will have to go to the respective if section and remove the code. With the other option, you could just remove the file.

**Cons:**
It would need at most 9 IF statements to return the result set or even show a 404 error page (ie, invalid $_GET value).

**Have 10 different pages:**

**Pros:**
No need of IF statements. So it would be a bit faster to load any of the tabs as well as to return the 404 error page.

**Cons:**
You will need to copy the template in 10 files. However, as the tabs count are never going to be much and creating them would be so easy by copying the first file, it is not going to take much time. Couple with that, the other method still require you add if statements, there is not much difference as far as development time is concerned.

So I would go with the second option of multiple static files. The $_GET option would be preferred if you are going to have a lot of dynamic pages (tabs) so you don't need to create many static pages. Since tabs are never going to be more (10 would be max I guess), I would say the second option is recommended here.

Note: The above comparison is between single page with 10 IFs and 10 separates pages. With single page with $_GET file include with whitelisting (single IF) option, the performance difference compared to separate pages is even less as a 404 page will return after a single IF & array check rather than 10 IFs. So you can ultimately do whichever is easiest for you as far as development is concerned.